# Skype version says it is older than it is

Tags: skype, versions

*OS: Ubuntu 12.04*
**Problem:** When I try to login to Skype, it says ¨cannot connect to server¨ - i understand that Skype no longer connects to server when the Skype version is less than 4.3, so my problem is as follows:

**Skype Version**
When I ask terminal for Skype version, it says the Skype version I have is 4.3
But when I open the Skype application (the only one available) it says it is version 4.0
I have removed and reinstalled it but it just produces the same problem.
How do I solve this problem?
- Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Problem solved after installing software updates and then reinstalling Skype v4.3

Comment: There is no link here, could you please update it?

Comment: There isn´t meant to be a link. I was just explaining how I solved it in case others had the same problem. No need to rate it down!

Comment: Not me, you could explain more in detail about what you did. I think this would be helpful to other users.